# writing a number as the sum of squares of $k$ numbers

Tags: number-theory

Consider a natural number $m$.Is there a way of counting for writing $m$  as the sum of squares of $k$ non-negative integers?That is,if $f(m)$ is the number of solutions $$\sum_{i=1}^k x_i^2=m \,\, ,x_i \geq 0,\,$$  could we somehow compute $$f(m)?$$ What about $f(m^2)?$ Can we interpret  $f(m^2)$ as the number of points on a $k-dimensional $ sphere (centered at the origin)  at integer distance $m$ from the origin? 
Any suggestions \hints are highly appreciated.

Comment: See "Number of partitions of $n$ into squares": https://oeis.org/A001156

Comment: For some $k$ , there are formulas.

Comment: could  you kindly refer

Comment: Of course you can compute it: it's a finite search. If you are asking for a closed formula or an algorithm with better performance than a brute force search, then you should say so. (Also, you need to require $x_i > 0$ not $x_i \ge 0$, otherwise there are always infinitely many solutions.)